# SSIS: CSV using decimal and whole numbers in same column

Tags: sql, csv, ssis

I have a CSV which uses whole numbers (100,0) and decimals (2.27, 88.53) in the same column and I can't seem to nail down what the data type should be in the flat file connection manager.

I've tried using Numeric (18,2), which will work if I eliminate the whole numbers in the CSV, but will fail if I add them back.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error message when nothing is changed in the file?

Comment: Error message and can you provide a sample of what the data looks like showing both numbers?